# Divergent , convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that,product of a divergent sequence and a null sequence is also divergent.I have the proof of product of a convergent sequence and a bounded sequence converges to 0.Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. A product of a divergent sequence and a null sequence can converge or it can diverge. Let us consider, for example,
$$
n\cdot\frac1n
$$
and
$$
n^2\cdot\frac1n.
$$